# Cannot creat foreign key mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql, postgresql

I am trying to  creat a foreign  key  as this code bellow, but I am getting the follow error, I did already check the fields and it has the same type as you can see **int(6) not null** but I am still getting this erro

**#1005 - Cannot creat table unicesumar.br_funcionarios (erro no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

```
CREATE TABLE `br_users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `COD_USER` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `SUPERIOR` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AREA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SENHA` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATIVO` int(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `br_funcionarios` (
 `ID` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `COD_USER_FK` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `CPF` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `RG` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TELEFONE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ENDERECO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CTP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `NOME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(COD_USER_FK) REFERENCES BR_USERS(COD_USER)
)
```

I am using mysql on xampp via phpMyAdmin
I already googled about it but I am still stuck on this situation
could some one help me thanks

Comment: `br_users.cod_user` needs to be `unique` to be marked as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be referencing the primary key of the table.

What would stop you of having two different records with the same COD_USER in br_users?

In such case which record should be referenced?

Comment: id - is an automatic generated code, and cod_user is an  manually code that you can creat for each user, I'll try to refer it to the id

Comment: thank  you  it solved my problem I just removed the id, and made the cod_user in br_users as primary key without auto_increment and it worked porpely :)